# JS holding down a key has a delay

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am learning  JavaScript and I am trying to program a small game. 
I want that something in my game moves consistently while I hold down a key. 
This is what I came up with so far:

```
document.onkeydown = onKeyDownListener;

function onKeyDownListener(evt) {
    var keyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == 37) {
        move();
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I press down the key move gets called once, then there is a pause and after that pause move gets called repeatedly as I intend. It goes 
like this: m......mmmmmmmmm when 'm' stands for move and'.' is the pause. 
Is there a way to get rid of the pause?

Here is a GIF of what happens:

[image: GIF of my problem]

Comment: That's how your keyboard works. Key repeat does not start immediately; otherwise typing would be very frustrating.

Comment: You are right, that this behaviour does serve a purpose and I am very aware of that. But as I explained I dont't want this behaviour in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you have this problem because you're not depending on a game loop to run your game. If you were, you wouldn't be running into this problem because the game loop at each interval would check if the key is pressed. Your web app is only reacting to each key press as they happen.

I highly recommend you read this tutorial:

**W3 HTML Game - Game Controllers**

https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_movement.asp

Read the "Keyboard as Controller" section. The "setInterval" method induces the game loop in this example.

I used it as a reference to write game code for myself.

This is code from the W3 tutorial. It also goes on to teach collision detection as well.

```
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false; 
        })
    }, 
    clear : function(){
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

 function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0; 
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.speedX = -1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.speedX = 1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.speedY = -1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.speedY = 1; }
    myGamePiece.newPos(); 
    myGamePiece.update();
}
```

Comment: I followed this tutorial on Udemy https://www.udemy.com/how-to-program-games/ and now I want to build more functions into the game. I do use a game loop. If you want to you can look at the full code here: https://jpst.it/1cBSK I tried the answer from @Gorgamite and after adding some inertia/acceleration it works fine now. Anyway thank you for your answer and the link :)

Comment: @Yannic It looks like you weren't originally setting the "arrowLeftDown" boolean on keyup and keydown rather than simplying calling a "move()" when the key was pressed resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
document.onkeydown = onKeyDownListener;
var keyDown = false;
function onKeyDownListener(evt) {
   if(evt.keyCode == 37) {
keyDown = true;
   }
}

document.onkeyup = function(evt){
 if(evt.keyCode == 37) {
keyDown = false;
   }
}

setInterval(function(){
if(keyDown){
player.x--;
}
},20)
```

It's not ideal, I know, but my best guess is it's an issue with keydown detection. This way, for as long as you're holding down that key, it will move until you let go of the key.

Comment: That matches with the idea I had to respond this.

Comment: It may not begin repeatedly, but wouldn't it start the keydown, register one key press, then after a short pause resume?

Comment: @Gorgamite yes sorry I didn't read the code correctly; this might work, though it might catch some repeats that aren't real when the interval timer happens to fire *right* before a "keyup". For the OP's purposes that may be OK.

Comment: True.... well given it will only be incorrectly going off for 1/50th of a second, I think the collateral is minimal